# stanford-openie: couldn't load clauseSearcherModel model due to serialVersionUID incompatible

Tags: stanford-nlp

Running stanford-openie from eclipse, the following exception occurred:

Could not load clause splitter model at edu/stanford/nlp/models/naturalli/clauseSearcherModel.ser.gz: class java.io.InvalidClassException: edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.ClauseSplitterSearchProblem$8; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 4145523451314579506, local class serialVersionUID = -7360029270983346606

Both openie code and openie models are latest, downloaded from http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.shtml.

Comment: When did you download the models? If you have an older version of the models or an older version of the code, this error will come up. But, trying it now from the jars on the website I can't replicate the error.

Comment: Thank you Gabor. I downloaded both code and models yesterday. I am aware the models are created by 1.8.0_31 (according to manifest file) whilst I am using 1.8.0_66. But it should not be problem, right? Besides, I found in your code that DEFAULT_FEATURIZER in ClauseSplitterSearchProblem.java has serialVersionUID = 4145523451314579506l. I don't know why the jvm thinks the serialVersionUID is -7360029270983346606 when deserializing it. The JVM problem?

Comment: Does the error occur on the command line? For example, if you run: `java -mx1g -cp stanford-openie.jar:stanford-openie-models.jar edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE`

Comment: I ran it from eclipse. I did this because before that I failed to execute the command line as you posted on Windows powershell and cygwin, got "Error: Could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE". The thing is, when I execute "java -mx1g -cp stanford-openie.jar edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE", the main class can be found (but, of course, it can't go on because models are missing).

Comment: The failure in command line was my fault. Sorry for misleading. But the exception is still there when running from eclipse.

Comment: Did you load the source code into eclipse, or are you linking to the jar files in your classpath? Does making a new project / rebuilding the current project help?

Comment: Thank you Gabor! Previously I loaded the source code into eclipse as a new project, and the serialVersionUID exception occurred. But after I read your comment 2 minute ago I tried creating a new project and linking jars, and it worked. However, it would be great if I can play with the source code :) I am reading your paper and trying to understand your algorithm.

Comment: In theory the source code should also work. But, if nothing else, you can use the [Github repo for CoreNLP](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP) in its place, and that'll always give you the most recent code.